# Fast way for weighted counting of numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 2D numpy arrays with the same shape:

```
idx = np.array([[1, 2, 5, 6],[1, 3, 5, 2]])
val = np.array([[0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2], [0.1, 0., 0.8, 0.2]])
```

I know that we can use `np.bincount` setting `val` as weights:

```
np.bincount(idx.reshape(-1), weights=val.reshape(-1))
```

But this is not exactly what I want. `np.bincount` put zeros where the indexes do not exist. In the example, the results are:

```
array([0. , 0.2, 0.7, 0. , 0. , 1.1, 0.2])
```

But I do not want these extra zeros for the non-exists indexes. I want the weighted counts corresponds to `np.unique(idx)`

```
array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6])
```

And my expected results are:

```
array([0.2, 0.7, 0., 1.1, 0.2])
```

Anyone has an idea to do it efficiently? My `idx` and `val` are very large with more than 1 Million elements.

Comment: Use `np.unique` with `return_inverse=True`?

Comment: I do not see `np.unique` accepts weights as an input.

Comment: You use the inverse map that `unique` returns with `bincount`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1:

Use `np.unique` with `return_inverse=True`.

```
idx = np.array([[1, 2, 5, 6],[1, 3, 5, 2]])
val = np.array([[0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2], [0.1, 0., 0.8, 0.2]])

unq,inv=np.unique(idx,return_inverse=True)
np.bincount(inv,val.reshape(-1))
# array([0.2, 0.7, 0. , 1.1, 0.2])
```

Method 2:

Use bincount and then remove the (genuine) zeros.

```
np.bincount(idx.reshape(-1),val.reshape(-1))[np.bincount(idx.reshape(-1)).nonzero()]
# array([0.2, 0.7, 0. , 1.1, 0.2])
```

Which is better will depend on how spread out `idx` is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy library effectively.

Check this out:

```
output = []
for i in np.unique(idx):
    wt = (idx == i)
    if i == 0:
        zeros = wt*(idx+1)
        l = np.sum(zeros*val)
    else:
        zeros = wt*idx
        l = np.sum(zeros*val)/i
    output.append(l)
print(output)
```

This is pretty fast. I hope it helps.

Comment: Intuitively,  for-loops should be slow though.

Answer (score 2):

As you may know, having for loops in python is not a good idea for efficiency:

You can try indexing the output of the bincount with the np.unique method:

```py
>>> np.bincount(idx.reshape(-1), val.reshape(-1))[np.unique(idx)]
array([0.2, 0.7, 0. , 1.1, 0.2])
```

If you just want to rid off from zeros probably this is the fastest way.

Answer (score 2):

The key to success is to:

- perform mapping of *unique* values from *idx* to consecutive integers,
  starting from *0*,
- compute bincount on the result of the above mapping, instead of *idx*
  itself.

The code to do it (quite concise and without any loop) is:

```
unq = np.unique(idx)
mapper = pd.Series(range(unq.size), index=unq)
np.bincount(mapper[idx.reshape(-1)], weights=val.reshape(-1))
```

For your sample data, the result is:

```
array([0.2, 0.7, 0. , 1.1, 0.2])
```